# how do you add values from a list separately if one variable has two possible outcomes

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

This assignment calls another function:

```
def getPoints(n):
    n = (n-1) % 13 + 1
    if n == 1:
        return [1] + [11]
    if 2 <= n <= 10:
        return [n]
    if 11 <= n <= 13:
        return [10]
```

So my assignment wants me to add the sum of all possible points from numbers from a list of 52 numbers. This is my code so far.

```
def getPointTotal(aList):
    points = []
    for i in aList:
        points += getPoints(i)
        total = sum(points)   
    return aList, points, total
```

However the issue is that the integer 1 has two possible point values, 1 or 11. When I do the sum of the points it does everything correctly, but it adds 1 and 11 together whereas I need it to compute the sum if the integer is 1 and if the integer is 11.

So for example:

```
>>>getPointTotal([1,26, 12]) # 10-13 are worth 10 points( and every 13th number that equates to 10-13 using n % 13.
>>>[21,31] # 21 if the value is 1, 31 if the value is 11.
```

Another example:

```
>>>getPointTotal([1,14]) # 14 is just 14 % 13 = 1 so, 1 and 1.
>>>[2, 12, 22] # 1+1=2, 1+11=12, 11+11=22
```

My output is:

```
>>>getPointTotal([1,14])
>>>[24] #It's adding all of the numbers 1+1+11+11 = 24.
```

So my question is, is how do I make it add the value 1 separately from the value 11 and vice versa. So that way when I do have 1 it would add all the values and 1 or it would add all the values and 11.

Comment: This question is not clear. 1) Please show the code for `getPoints()` or a simplified version. It is not clear how it works or even if it returns an integer or a list containing one integer. 2) Your line `total = sum(points)` should line up under the `for` line, or `total` will be evaluated more often than needed. 3) The output does not match the example output you give.

Comment: Dedent the `total` line so it is only computed once, after the loop.  Since this a homework, I will just give a hint.  Look at the pattern of correct ansers.  In [1, 14], there are 2 values worth 1 or 11 (1 + 10) points.  The possible totals are 2, 2+10, 2+20.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I added the code for the called in function.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I de-dented the total line and still computes the same total I've been getting which has been 24. So it is still adding 1+1+11+11. I'm stuck on how I can separate the calculations between 1+1, 1+11, and 11+11.

Comment: Whats your desired output?  If i run `getPoints(1)` I get `[1, 11]`. Is this what you want separately?

Comment: @estebanpdl yeah I want it to compute all possible outcomes. so 1 by itself should return 1, 11. However when I attempt to get the sum. It adds 1 and 11 together where it should make it separate. So instead of 1+11+2=14 it should do 1+2=3, 11+2=13 [3, 13] like so.

Comment: They're together because `def getPoints()` create a single list when this is `True`: `if n == 1`. `[1] + [11] = [1, 11]`, so you are returning both numbers.

Comment: Let's take this as an example: `getPointTotal([1,14])` it gives this result: `([1, 14], [1, 11, 1, 11], 24)`. right? So, output should be this `([1, 14], [1, 11], 12)`?

Comment: If the input into the shell is getPointTotal([1,14]) it should return [2,12,22] as it should be taking either of the values in a separate equation. like 1+1=2, 1+11=12, 11+11=22 for [1,11, 1,11]. I'm sorry it's so hard to explain, I've haven't had an issue like this before and am unsure how to express the issue it a better manner.

Comment: Would there be a way to separate the list it creates in the new function like splice it for example then add it then join them again?

Comment: The code you've shown returns a 3-tuple with the list of cards, the list of scores, and the total. Do you actually want need some or all of that in your fixed version that returns all possible scores?

Comment: I was using the aList and points to try and figure out what was going on. I know I should of probably used print to do that, but I didn't think of it at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a mistake in storing all the values returned from `getPoints()`. You should store only the possible totals for the points returned so far. You can store all those in a set, and update them with the all the possible values returned from `getPoints()`. A set will automatically remove duplicate scores, such as 1+11 and 11+1. You can change the set to a sorted list at the end. Here is my code:

```
def getPointTotal(aList):
    totals = {0}
    for i in aList:
        totals = {p + t for p in getPoints(i) for t in totals}
    return sorted(list(totals))
```

I get these results:

```
>>> print(getPointTotal([1,26, 12]))
[21, 31]
>>> print(getPointTotal([1,14]))
[2, 12, 22]
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to do `newtotals = newtotals | {p + t}` instead of `newtotals.add(p+t)`. While it may be less clear for a new Python student, you could go even further and use a set comprehension to replace both of the inner loops (and do away with `newtotals` completely): `for i in alist: totals = {p + t for p in getpoints(i) for t in totals}`

Comment: @Blckknght: I saw your comment just as I was finishing my revised code. It happens to be exactly as you recommend--but I honestly did not use your comment! You clearly had a good idea, of course. I used the `|` operator in my first version since the [Python tutorial for sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) does not mention the `add()` method and I forgot it.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I've been stressing out on this all day.

Answer (score 1):

Rory Daulton's answer is a good one, and it efficiently gives you the different totals that are possible. I want to offer another approach which is not necessarily better than that one, just a bit different. The benefit to my approach is that you can see the sequence of scores that lead to a given total, not only the totals at the end.

```
def getPointTotal(cards):
    card_scores = [getPoints(card) for card in cards] # will be a list of lists
    combos = {sorted(scores) for scores in itertools.product(*card_scores)}
    return [(scores, sum(scores)) for scores in combos]
```

The key piece of this code is the call to `itertools.product(*card_scores)`. This takes the lists you got from `getPoints` for each of the cards in the input list and gets all the combinations. So  `product([1, 11], [1, 11], [10])` will give `(1, 1, 10)`, `(1, 11, 10)`, `(11, 1, 10)`, and `(11, 11, 10)`.

This is probably a bit overkill for blackjack scoring where there are not going to be many variations on the scores for a given set of cards. But for a different problem (i.e. a different implementation of the `getPoints` function), it could be very interesting.